# Can change the time format in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Is it possible to somehow change the time format in postgresql? At the moment I have the format `time without time zone` and it is displayed  `hh:mm:ss`, and how can I make it in `hh:mm`?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: You can add it to `current_date` and use the regular timestamp formatting functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The display format of `date`, `time` and `timestamp` values can be changed with [`to_char` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html):

```
SELECT to_char(current_timestamp, 'HH:MI') -- or HH24:MI if want 24 hours
```